# Single quote in SQL WHERE IN statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, where-clause

Okay so my T-SQL statement is the following

```
IF @dept <> '' BEGIN
    SET @query = @query + ' AND T6.Region2 IN (' + REPLACE(@dept, '^', '''') + ') '
END
```

This is basically for a French site and the region names have ' in the names. What I'm trying to do is pass something like the following to SQL

```
@dept = 'Cote-d^Armor', 'Val-d^Oise'
```

and replace the `^` with a `'`. When I do a replace it's just causing an error as if the replaced `^` is a `'` and escaping the rest of the code.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: If you used parameterized queries you wouldn't have to struggle with this and your code would be far less prone to sql injection. The reason your code isn't working is because you would have to add 2 more single quotes inside your replace. That's because to delimit a single quote requires 2.

Comment: Can you give an example of doing this better please? I'm very Jnr when it comes to TSQL, thanks

Comment: The replace would be like this. REPLACE(@dept, '^', ''''''). I can't give you an example of parameterizing your query because there is no code here. This looks like it is part of a larger sql script that is using dynamic sql (something else you could probably eliminate).

Answer (score 0):

You need some extra quotes outside the replace. Try this:

```
IF @dept <> '' BEGIN
SET @query = @query + ' AND T6.Region2 IN (''' + REPLACE(@dept, '^', '''') + ''') '
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't swap "'" for "^" to store it and then try and convert it back. It would be much simpler to store "Cote-d'Armor", then in your stored procedure whenever there is a "'" in the search string, to double it.

SQL Server can happily cope with ' and " in the data, they just need to be escaped properly.